# Best practice for mapping Multiple-Choice-Answers to a Rails Database-Model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

If i got a Model für my Question and each Question can have multiple Choices. 
What is the best way of storing the corresponding Answers ?
I got 2 Main Ideas :

1.) Create an Answer Model and store a binary Code inside one Attribute like 010 for non yes no
and reference to the corresponding Question

2.) Create an Answer Model and a Choice-Answer-Model .. so every Answer can have multiple Choice-Answers .. my Answer then references to my Question and my Choice-Answers to my Choices

So my question now is, how would you do this ?
Are my approaches good enough to implement or are there some better approaches of doing this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My opinion:

Create `choice` table,

```
(question_id,:content,:is_true)
```

No need to store the answe code like 1010. Can findout from options

```
Question.first.choices.pluck(:is_true)
```